# How to return a 403 in a ViewSet instead of 404

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an API and have this ViewSet:

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # API endpoint that allows projects to be viewed or edited.
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    authentication_classes = used_authentication_classes
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def functions(self, request, pk=None):
        project = self.get_object()
        if project is None:
            return Response({'detail': 'Missing project id'}, status=404)
        return Response([FunctionSerializer(x).data for x in Function.objects.filter(project=project)])
```

A permission system is attached to this API. The permissions work fine for a single resource. But when I call `api/projects` which should return all of the projects the user has access to, it does in fact return all of the projects, regardless whether the user should be able to GET a certain project in the list or not.

So I overwrote the `get_queryset` method to only return the projects the user has access to:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_staff:
        return Project.objects.all()
    else:
        return Project.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.user)
```

This works, but now the API returns a 404 instead of a 403 when I ask for a specific resource I don't have access to.

I understand why, because the PK from the resource I try to get is undefined since I only return projects the user has access to. What I don't understand is how to fix this.

Does anyone know how I can make it return a 403, or maybe an idea towards where I should look?

Comment: `self.request.user.is_staff or self.request.user.is_staff` both `is_staff`?

Comment: In [this issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1439), the rest framework author argues that if the user doesn't have read permissions then you shouldn't let them know whether the object exists or not, so `404` is a deliberate choice. At the bottom of the issue there's a link to an extension that might help if you really want `403` (but it's from 2014 so it might not be applicable any more).

Comment: @BearBrown a forgotten copy pasta, updated

Comment: How about overriding `def list` and filtering `user=self.request.user.user` instead of overriding `def get_queryset`

Comment: @Alasdair I think the reason that it returns a 404 is:
1. Get all projects, filtering on whether the user has the correct permissions
2. User does not have to access to specific project he requested, so the queryset returns nothing.
3. DRF tries to get_object on a query_set/pk (I don't precisely know how it gets a single resource) that is empty, fails, and returns a 404

Comment: I wasn't trying to explain how the code works - I was pointing out that returning 404 is a deliberate decision, so that you don't reveal the existence of objects to users that don't have permission to read them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @Alasdair say the 404 is a deliberate choice, but if you still want to get 403 you can try:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    allow_all = user.is_superuser or user.is_staff
    if self.action == 'list' and not allow_all:
        return Project.objects.filter(user=user)
    return Project.objects.all()
```

Comment: The request does not contain an `action` attribute. Edit: Turns out it's in `self` and not in `request`. Testing it now.

Comment: @Snackoverflow Change `self.request.action` to `self.action`.

Comment: After tweaking it a bit, it works perfectly! In my case I have a 1:1 relationship with the Django `User` model, so I have to do `...filter(user=user.user)`. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help! sorry for typo with action,